# Node Puppeteer - unable to step through form if it has a Google AutoComplete Element

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, testing, puppeteer, google-developer-tools

I am developing an E2E test for my app. In order to step through the whole workflow and make sure it works from beginning to the end.

Now given a form with an autocomplete element:

[image]

I am able to type in the form but unable to select an option. And hence advance through the form. I have tried so far:

E.g. method 1 - clicking an option

```
...
await page.type('input[id=ac]', 'san fran', {delay: 100})
await page.mouse.click(65, 600);
...
```

E.g. method 2 - automating keys

```
...
await page.type('input[id=ac]', 'san fran', {delay: 100})
await page.focus("#ac");
await page.type(String.fromCharCode(40)); //down arrow
await page.type(String.fromCharCode(13)); //enter
...
```

I only saw [one Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53993443/using-autocomplete-in-puppeteer) that said there may be security restrictions but I can't confirm it by looking at any official documentation.

How can I select an autocomplete option?

Full Code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false }); 
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('http://localhost:8080/#/');
  ...
  await page.type('input[id=ac]', 'san fran', {delay: 100})
  await page.mouse.click(65, 600);
  ...
  
})();
```

Comment: Side question. if I'm unable to step through this form element what alternatives do I have for bypassing this form when doing my regression tests?

Comment: The SO answer you've found was not about _Google Places Autocomplete_, but HTML's native autocomplete.   
Normally what you are trying to achieve is possible. Can you share the DOM of the opened autocomplete list? There should be a list of `.pac-item` / `.pac-item-selected` etc. elements which you could click on with puppeteer.

Comment: `const addressSelector = "#formGridAddress";
  await page.click(addressSelector);
  await page.type(addressSelector, "bos", { delay: 100 });
  await page.waitForTimeout(1000);
  await page.keyboard.press("ArrowDown");
  await page.keyboard.press("Enter");` This worked for me